# How to update an embedded document into a nested array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this kind of structure into a Mongo collection :

```
{
  "_id": "12345678",
  "Invoices": [
    {
      "_id": "123456789",
      "Currency": "EUR",
      "DueTotalAmountInvoice": 768.3699999999999,
      "InvoiceDate": "2016-01-01 00:00:00.000",
      "Items": [
        {
          "Item": 10,
          "ProductCode": "ABC567",
          "Quantity": 1
        },
        {
          "Item": 20,
          "ProductCode": "CDE987",
          "Quantity": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "87654321",
      "Currency": "EUR",
      "DueTotalAmountInvoice": 768.3699999999999,
      "InvoiceDate": "2016-01-01 00:00:00.000",
      "Items": [
        {
          "Item": 30,
          "ProductCode": "PLO987",
          "Quantity": 1,
          "Units": "KM3"
        },
        {
          "Item": 40,
          "ProductCode": "PLS567",
          "Quantity": 1,
          "DueTotalAmountInvoice": 768.3699999999999
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So I have a first object storing several Invoices and each Invoice is storing several Items. An item is an embedded document.
So in relational modelisation :
A customer has 1 or several Invoice
An Invoice has 1 or several Item

I am facing an issue since I am trying to update a specific Item into a specific a specific Invoice. For example I want to change the quantity of the item 10 in Invoice 123456789.

How is it possible to do that in Mongodb ?

I tried :

- Push statement but it doesn't seem to work for nested arrays
- arrayFilters but it doesn't seem to work for embedded document in nested arrays (only simple value arrays).

Can you give me some advice about it ?

Thank you !

Comment: what is your mongo server version ? run db.version() to know the  version. can you show the query with array filters ?

Comment: @Junayy, `arrayFilters` wont work properly unless you're executing the query from latest mongo shell. Also the statement `I tried arrayFilters but it doesn't seem to work for embedded document in nested arrays` isnt true.

Comment: @Veeram I am on mongo 3.6

Comment: Are u executing in a mongo shell or third party tool?

Comment: @Rahul Raj mongo shell

Comment: @Junayy check below query, its working on my mongo shell.

Comment: @Junayy I have edited my answer with all the changes you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your problem description here:

`For example I want to change the quantity of the item 10 in Invoice 123456789.` I just changed the `Quantity` to 3. You can perform any operations here as you want. You just need to take note of how I used `arrayFilters` here.

Try this query:

```
db.collection.update(
 {"_id" : "12345678"},
 {$set:{"Invoices.$[element1].Items.$[element2].Quantity":3}},
 {multi:true, arrayFilters:[ {"element1._id": "123456789"},{ 
  "element2.Item": { $eq: 10 }} ]}
)
```

The above query successfully executed from mongo shell (Mongo 3.6.3). And I see this result:

```
/* 1 */
{
"_id" : "12345678",
"Invoices" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : "123456789",
        "Currency" : "EUR",
        "DueTotalAmountInvoice" : 768.37,
        "InvoiceDate" : "2016-01-01 00:00:00.000",
        "Items" : [ 
            {
                "Item" : 10,
                "ProductCode" : "ABC567",
                "Quantity" : 3.0
            }, 
            {
                "Item" : 20,
                "ProductCode" : "CDE987",
                "Quantity" : 1
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "87654321",
        "Currency" : "EUR",
        "DueTotalAmountInvoice" : 768.37,
        "InvoiceDate" : "2016-01-01 00:00:00.000",
        "Items" : [ 
            {
                "Item" : 30,
                "ProductCode" : "PLO987",
                "Quantity" : 1,
                "Units" : "KM3"
            }, 
            {
                "Item" : 40,
                "ProductCode" : "PLS567",
                "Quantity" : 1,
                "DueTotalAmountInvoice" : 768.37
            }
        ]
    }
 ]
}
```

[image]

Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Mongo Db has a way to get the specific array element by using its index. For example, you have an array and you need to get [your] index, then in mongo we use dot . but not braces [ ] !! And one thing is important either! - If you are getting the embedded value (in object or array) you must use " " for your way so if you are changing your value inside this must be like that:

```
   yourModel.findOneAndUpdate(
     { _id: "12345678" },
     {
       $set: {
         "Invoices.0.Items.0.Quantity": 10,
       },
     }
   );
```

0 - is your element indexes in the array!
$set is the operator to set new value
10 - new value

Else you can go further, you can construct your way to the value with the variable indexes. Use string template

```
   yourModel.findOneAndUpdate(
     { _id: "12345678" },
     {
       $set: {
         [`Invoices.${invoiceIndex}.Items.${itemIndex}.Quantity`]:newValue ,
       },
     }
   );
```

it is the same but you can paste variable indexes