# populate embed array mongoose 5.0. Nested ref

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate, mongoose-plugins

This is the first model. It's located in the folder called models/user.js

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var UserSchema = Schema({

        publications: [{
            description: String,
            categories: [{
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Category.subcategories'
            }]
    }]
```

The model category. It's located in the folder called models/category.js

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var CategorySchema = Schema({
        name: String,
        subcategories: [{
            name: String
        }]
    });
```

Look that The UserSchema has categories. This one has this reference:

```
ref: 'Category.subcategories'
```

I have a folder called controller. The next json is from controller/category.js

```
'use strict'

var Categories = require('./models/category');


    function getCategories(req, res){

        Categories.find({},(err, categories) =>{
            if(err){
                res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error en la peticion' });
                return;   
            }

            if(!categories){
                res.status(404).send({ message: 'No hay categories' });
                return
            }

            res.status(200).send({ categories });
        });
    }


    module.exports = {
        getCategories
    }
```

The json of Category looks like this.

```
{
    "categories": [
        {
            "subcategories": [
                {
                    "_id": "5ae4a8b0a7510e3bd80917db",
                    "name": "subcategory1"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5ae4a8b0a7510e3bd80917da",
                    "name": "subcategory2"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5ae4a8b0a7510e3bd80917d9",
                    "name": "subcategory3"
                }
            ],
            "_id": "5ae4a8b0a7510e3bd80917d7",
            "name": "Category1",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "subcategories": [
                {
                    "_id": "5ae4a8b0a7510e3bd80917e0",
                    "name": "subcategory1"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5ae4a8b0a7510e3bd80917df",
                    "name": "subcategory2"
                }
            ],
            "_id": "5ae4a8b0a7510e3bd80917dc",
            "name": "Category2",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Each subcategory2 belongs to one Category.

This one is in controller/user.js

The user whithout populate will looks like this

```
        User.find({}, (err, publications) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(500).send({
                        message: "Error en la peticion " + err
                    });
                    return;
                }

                if (!publications) {
                    res.status(404).send({
                        message: "Publicacion no encontrada"
                    });
                    return;
                }

res.status(200).send(publications);
```

result

```
"publications": [
            {
                "description": "abc",
                "categories": [
                    "5ae4a8b0a7510e3bd80917db",
                    "5ae4a8b0a7510e3bd80917da"
                ]

            },
            {
                "description": "abcddvas asa",
                "categories": [
                    "5ae4a8b0a7510e3bd80917e0"
                ]                
            },
]
```

I need to populate categories when I do this.

```
User.find().populate('publications.categories').then(function (err, posa) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send(err);
                return;
            }
            res.status(500).send(posa);
            return;
        });
```

So the final json should look like this:

```
"publications": [
                {
                    "description": "abc",
                    "categories": [
                        {
                          "_id": "5ae4a8b0a7510e3bd80917db",
                          "name": "subcategory1"
                        },
                        {
                           "_id": "5ae4a8b0a7510e3bd80917da",
                           "name": "subcategory2"
                        }
                    ]

                },
                {
                    "description": "abcddvas asa",
                    "categories": [
                        {
                           "_id": "5ae4a8b0a7510e3bd80917e0",
                           "name": "subcategory1"
                        }
                    ]                
                },
    ]
```

But The result does not show me the final json.

I see that there is a option called Dynamic References. 
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

The example show this

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  connections: [{
    kind: String,
    item: { type: ObjectId, refPath: 'connections.kind' }
  }]
});
```

Instead of use ref, uses refPath. But for me didn't work that.

I tried to use this

```
https://github.com/buunguyen/mongoose-deep-populate
```

but that didn't work for me.

I tried to do a lot of tries. None works for me. I have been searching days and trying a lot of things but I have not been able to resolve this.

Comment: How to you compile your schema? where is your model function and how do you include your sub-documents [your arrays of objects] into your document?

Comment: I put more info. Is it clearer?

Comment: 1) I compile the schema Using mongoose. 2) The model function is in Controller/user.js.  3) I include the array of objectsId into the document. I reply all the answer. Is it clearer?. I am desperate trying to give solution to this. Please let me know if you need more info

Comment: You know what? I posted almost a tutorial about the proyect and how to run with the link to download the proyect. I hope tha this is so much clear

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50139312/populate-nested-array-of-nested-ref

Comment: So know you know how it works. how it run. With the link that I posted You will know everything. So what you say now? do you need more details?

Comment: I do not even know where to start to help you with this. It is not that the more info you post the better. Quite the contrary, often posting the specific error that you get will be more efficient. So rather than saying "nothing works", be specific about the error that you get...Since you are trying to build a MVC application, start with small things and test your app for each piece of code you write.

Comment: The app as it stands is an utter mess (sorry to be brutally blunt). The app.js, which is the entry point for the app, misses a lot of middleware functions and the basic functionality for an HTTP server. The controllers contain hard coded data that should be in the model. The models contain schemas with sub-documents that are not correctly implemented. I could go on.

Comment: Please sort your app out first and then when you run into some specific errors or issues, come back for some help.

Comment: I do not understand why you asked 'how to compile the schema' and when you say 'array of subdocument objectid' the code shows that. I felt that I lost my time trying to explain you just a specific thing.

Comment: I only wanted just populate a nested array of nested model. Like for example ref: model.property. And with that I wanted just populated that. So you said that you wanted all many things and changes everything.

Comment: Nothing about you said help me. I spent a lot of time. In this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49754557/how-to-update-an-embedded-document-into-a-nested-array the person just put the schema and none said 'how do you compile your schema. show me everything... you know what you are wrong I won't help you because you have bad things. '

Comment: can you identify the differences between your question and that [question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49754557/how-to-update-an-embedded-document-into-a-nested-array). I am sorry if my questions did not help you this time

Comment: what about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28179720/mongoose-populate-nested-array

Comment: the people did not say 'where is your model function' and 'how do you compile ...'